# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in

Tags: php, smarty, smarty2

Got a warning like in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="kids_age_range">AGe  Range</label>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label class="control-label" for="k_1_5">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="kids_age_range[]" value="1-5" id="k_1_5" {if in_array('1-5', $job.kids_age_range)} checked{/if} /> 1-5 
                </label>                                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `$job.kids_age_range` store?

Comment: $job.kids_age_range is object where we can get the values in an array form like ['1-5']

Comment: If it's an object, then it isn't an array: you'll need to convert it to an actual PHP array, and then use that in your in_array() check

Comment: `$job.kids_age_range` looks like String rather an array, needs to be cast before being used as array. Probably what you are using can also be a JSON string array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $job.kids_age_range is a single dimensional array you will need to cast the object into an array before you can use it.

```
// Cast to an array
$array = (array) $job.kids_age_range;
```